# Automatically generating reference number

Tags: forms, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to develop a formula automatically to generate a unique reference number for each respondent on Google Forms.  I want these numbers to increase consecutively and start with 3790.

Can anyone help with this?

This is a formula I developed:

```
=arrayformula(if(row(A1:A)=1,"STOCK NUMBER",if(len(A1:A)>0,3787+row(A1:A),iferror(1/0))))
```

Will this work?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this site--I just changed it!

Comment: Ok, I'll do that--thank you!